# Delay GameCenter Authentication View Controller from being presentation - Swift 4.2

Tags: authentication, game-center, viewdidload, swift4.2

I am trying to make the `GameCenter` **Authentication View Controller** be delayed 2 seconds before being presented. There are about 2 seconds of button  animations that take place in my VC and I don't want them to be blocked by the presentation of the `GameCenter` **Authentication View Controller**. Any suggestions?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     // Game Center - Authentication of player
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAuthenticationViewController), name: NSNotification.Name(GameKitHelper.PresentAuthenticationViewController), object: nil)

     GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.authenticateLocalPlayer()
}

// Game Center - Presents authentication view controller
@objc func showAuthenticationViewController() {
    let gameKitHelper = GameKitHelper.sharedInstance
    if let authenticationViewController =
        gameKitHelper.authenticationViewController {
        self.present(authenticationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

// add this to deregister for notifications when the object is deallocated
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, good old **Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)** will get the job done. The 2.0 is for 2 seconds, but change it to however long you need.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {

         // Game Center - Authentication of player
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.showAuthenticationViewController), name: NSNotification.Name(GameKitHelper.PresentAuthenticationViewController), object: nil)

        GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.authenticateLocalPlayer()
    }
}
```